# How to integrate the following expression which doesn't converge?

Tags: integration

I read in [this paper](http://www.deeplook.ir/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/coulson1961-2.pdf) that 
$$f(r_{12})=8\pi^2 r_{12}\int\int \psi^2(r_1,r_2)r_1 r_2 dr_1 dr_2 \tag{1}$$
where $r_1$ and $r_2$ being allowed all values compatible with any given $r_{12}$. Thus eq (1) may be written
$$f(r_{12})=8\pi^2 r_{12} \{\int_{r_{12}}^\infty r_1 dr_1 \int_{r_1-r_{12}}^{r_1+r_{12}}r_2 \psi^2(r_1,r_2)dr_2+\int_0^{r_{12}} r_1 dr_1 \int_{r_{12}-r_1}^{r_{12}+r_1}r_2 \psi^2(r_1,r_2)dr_2\} \tag{2}$$
but in fact the first and third integrals in equation (2) don't converge. How can I obtain a result from equation (2) using a given $\psi$?

Comment: I’m not sure if my understanding is correct, but I think the author may have made a mistake in that equation, it really only makes sense if you put $dr_1$ after the second integral, so that the second integral occurs inside of the first. That way, the integral converges, and gives a proper representation of the region the author seems to be integrating over. Similarly, the fourth integral should occur inside of the third, but that doesn’t actually affect whether it converges.

Comment: @Robo300 Thanks a lot